# Sig fault in c iterating over a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, scope, singly-linked-list

I can't figure out why I am getting a seg fault when trying to move to the next node in a linked list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
    };


int main(void)
{    
    //create lists 
    struct ListNode lst1;
    struct ListNode lst2;

    //create tmp lists
    struct ListNode tmp_lst1;
    struct ListNode tmp_lst2;
    lst1.next = &tmp_lst1;
    lst2.next = &tmp_lst2;

    int nums[] = {2,4,3};
    int nums2[] = {5,6,4};
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]); i++)
    {
         
        tmp_lst1.val = nums[i];    // assign value to node
        struct ListNode tmp;      // create a new node 
        tmp_lst1.next = &tmp;    // point next node to the newly assigned one 
        tmp_lst1 = *tmp.next;   // jump to new node 
        printf("%d ",nums[i]);
    
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf(">>> %d \n",lst1.val);
    lst1 = *lst1.next;
    printf(">>> %d \n",lst1.val);
    lst1 = *lst1.next;
    printf(">>> %d \n",lst1.val);

    return 0; 
}
```

I am trying to figure out if I add the numbers in the `nums` to a linked list in the for loop but I keep on getting the sig fault error

Comment: `struct ListNode tmp; tmp_lst1.next = &tmp;` You can't do that. The lifetime of `tmp` is just one iteration of the `for` loop. Storing a pointer and using it outside that lifetime results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `tmp_lst1.next = &tmp;` <- tmp will cease to exist after the loop has finished, so its address is no longer valid.

Comment: You need to learn about dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`, `free` etc.). You cannot handle liked lists without. The overall approach here is totally wrong. Throw this code away.

Answer (score 1):

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]); i++)
{
     
    tmp_lst1.val = nums[i];    // assign value to node
    struct ListNode tmp;      // create a new node 
    tmp_lst1.next = &tmp;    // point next node to the newly assigned one 
    tmp_lst1 = *tmp.next;   // jump to new node 
    printf("%d ",nums[i]);

}
```

the lifetime of the object `tmp` is the block of the for loop. Outside the block the object is not alive. So all pointers that point to objects tmp are invalid. Dereferencing these pointers invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: understood so what do i do exactly because i moved `struct ListNode` outside the for loop but still got the same error

Comment: @prometheus You need to declare as many structure as many nodes you are going to append to the list. And all these objects shall be alive then you will traverse the list. You could declare an array of structures.